# How to prove $a_1 = 2$, $a_2 = 4$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2a_n+a_{n-1})$ for all $n \geq2$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation

Let $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 4$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{3}(2a_n+a_{n-1})$ for all $n \geq2$ Prove that for all positive integers $n$, $3 \leq a_n \leq4$

This was a practice problem in my textbook in the chapter of strong induction. It's not worth marks or anything I've just spent a while trying to figure how to prove this and I'm drawing a blank.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you know induction?

Comment: Well, it's false for $n=1$.

Comment: I edited, $a_1 = 3$ not $2$

Comment: ${a_n}=\frac{{{3}^{2-n}}\, {{\left( -1\right) }^{n}}}{4}+\frac{15}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

Because by the assumption of the induction  $$a_{n+1`}\geq\frac{1}{3}(2\cdot3+3)=3$$ and
$$a_{n+1`}\leq\frac{1}{3}(2\cdot4+4)=4.$$
Also, check $n=2$ and $n=3$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how are you plugging in 3 for $a_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, because by assumption of the induction we have $a_{n}\geq3$ and $a_{n-1}\geq3$ for all $n\geq3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Do you know how to parameterise the points of a closed interval $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 0):

$x^2-\frac{2}{3}x-\frac{1}{3}=(x-1)(x+\frac{1}{3})=0$ then $a_n=A(1)^n+B(\frac{1}{3})^n$.That $a_n=5-9(\frac{1}{3})^n$